# How to use remote db tables in current config?

Tags: database, wpdb, wp-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shared Members between two different wordpress installations with different databases](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70519/shared-members-between-two-different-wordpress-installations-with-different-data)

For example I have 2 different wordpress installations with different domains and hosts. Databases are separated too (two different databases).

I want to use  `www.b.com` mysql db tables on `www.a.com` `wp-config.php`. Is there any way to do that?

If I could register tables from a remote database, I could use that in site `b`:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wpsiteA_users');
```

Can I the database connection from site A on site B?

Comment: If this is in addition to your question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70519/shared-members-between-two-different-wordpress-installations-with-different-data/70581#70581 the two topics should be merged and the current question updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good reason to actually do this, but you can simply use what's in your config to point to another host.

[Right from the codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Database_Host).

```
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.example.com:3307');
```

Comment: If you do it this way wouldn't you still have to merge the two databases? And define the table prefixes differently to keep the inapstallations separate?

Comment: He never said anything about merging or sharing, he just said "use", but I'll vote to close it since his other question is the same and more clear.

Comment: If i use define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.example.com:3307');  , is this change all of connection for using database ? I mean, i want to get and register only remote spesific tables to current wordpress website, for example only users table. I dont want to change all of db path.  I mean, can i get remote spesific table only to my web site ? If this is possible, i will use remote user table but local content for my blog post, pages or other etc... I dont want to use all of remote db. I want only use remote db spesific table. Is this possible ? Help me please.

Comment: Yes this I do believe that this would change all of the connection. I don't think you can just share various tables remotely.